# InvalidOperationException while cloning a generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a really annoying problem.

What I want do to is just simply iterate on a generic List. This List is allowed to be modified on other Threads.

My first implementation throwed a InvalidOperationException because of this concurrent call. A I learned I am not allowed to add or remove Items to my list while iterating on this list.

Okay, so long time ago I started to use code like this everywhere I iterate collections :

```
foreach (CmdInterface cmd in new List<CmdInterface>(cmdList)) {
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I do not iterate the original List but a clone.
This seemed to work for a long time, but from time to time InvalidOperationException was thrown again, I was not able to figure out why. It toke my a lot of coffee and long days for searching what could I have done wrong.

The stacktrace of the exception is like this:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
```

So yesterday my idea was to have a look inside the used Construcor of List, to see how Microsoft implemented the cloning. I found this:

```
// Constructs a List, copying the contents of the given collection. The
    // size and capacity of the new list will both be equal to the size of the
    // given collection.
    //
    public List(IEnumerable<t> collection) {
        if (collection==null)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);

        ICollection<t> c = collection as ICollection<t>;
        if( c != null) {
            int count = c.Count;
            _items = new T[count];
            c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
            _size = count;
        }
        else {
            _size = 0;
            _items = new T[_defaultCapacity];

            using(IEnumerator<t> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
                while(en.MoveNext()) {
                    Add(en.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So as you can see, Microsoft itself is iterating over the Collection to clone. So this might be the point where in some rare situation changing the list might collide with cloning it.

So my question ist, what do you think, is this behavior by design or might it by some issue.
More important to me, what else then using the CopyConstructor can i do to create a clone of my List for iterating threadsafe over it.

Thanks for your help
Ronny

Comment: You have run into an edge case, the issue is not in your constructor, the issue is in the IEnumerable that you are passing it.

Comment: NoviceProgrammer: Sorry as i am not native englisch speaking, what do you mean by "edge case"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List<T>` is not thread safe as you have found out.  It simply iterates over the contents when required.

The errors you are experiencing are therefore by design.

As to why it has been implemented as such; Because synchronised access to variables is costly in terms of resources.  It is not the required behaviour in common instances and as such it's not implemented by default.  The fringe cases when synchronisation is required are to be handled via thread safe collections or the developers own locking mechanism.

There are variants of the collection types that provide thread safe calls, but you may also want to consider why you have a collection being accessed by multiple threads, and whether a custom lock is more useful than a blocking collection.

Thread safe collections overview - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Thread Safe `ConcurrentBag<T>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Kami, thanks for answering. Well, long time ago i learned about thread safe collections, but as far as i understand there is no equivalent to a list. Knowing the problem about that List is not threadsafe i tried to do it by myself bei using a Clone of my List. But my thoughts didn't went far enough to figure out that cloning a List use a GetEnumarator() too. Long story short, i put some "lock" to my code to go around these issues. Thank you

Comment: By the way, why i do access the List from two threads is just simple, one Thread collects some data to the List which is displayed by the GUI-Thread.